# Adding and reading json data stored in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a vuex store and i am adding some josn data and this is the format.

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "firstname": "toto",
        "lastname": "titi"
    },
    {   "id":2,
        "firstname": "one",
        "lastname": "two"
    }
]
```

I am adding the data on an on click action and this is the action method

```
addLink: function() {
var dt = '[{"id":1,"firstname":"xx","lastname": "yy"},{"id":2,"firstname": "one","lastname": "two"}]';
  this.ADD_LINK(dt)
  this.newLink = '';
},
```

The data is getting added to the store and i can access it like this

```
computed: {
    users(){
    return this.countLinks;
    }
  }
```

I can display the data this way `{{users}}` and this is getting displayed. This is because i clicked twice and added the json twice.

```
[ "[{\"id\":1,\"firstname\":\"xx\",\"lastname\": \"yy\"},{\"id\":2,\"firstname\": \"one\",\"lastname\": \"two\"}]", "[{\"id\":1,\"firstname\":\"xx\",\"lastname\": \"yy\"},{\"id\":2,\"firstname\": \"one\",\"lastname\": \"two\"}]" ]
```

However, when i try to use v-for

```
<ul id="users">
  <li v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
    {{ users.firstname}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

i cannot display any data and i have no error. How can i display the data saved in vuex?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `computed` property that returns the objects in one list parsed as `JSON`:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: () => ({
    users: [ "[{\"id\":1,\"firstname\":\"xx\",\"lastname\": \"yy\"},{\"id\":2,\"firstname\": \"one\",\"lastname\": \"two\"}]", "[{\"id\":1,\"firstname\":\"xx\",\"lastname\": \"yy\"},{\"id\":2,\"firstname\": \"one\",\"lastname\": \"two\"}]" ]
  }),
  computed: {
    usersList: function() {
       return this.users.flatMap(userList => JSON.parse(userList));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul id="users">
    <li v-for="(user, index) in usersList" :key="index">
      {{ user.firstname}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> **Note:** Since ids are not unique in your example, you can use an `index` in `v-for` as the `key`. Also, to show the first name, you need to use the `user` object.

**Another solution:** Parse `dt` in the store and use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to add the elements as objects to the initial list:

```js
let countLinks = [
  { "id":1,  "firstname": "toto", "lastname": "titi" },
  { "id":2, "firstname": "one", "lastname": "two" }
];
function ADD_LINK(dt) {
  countLinks = countLinks.concat(JSON.parse(dt));
}

const dt = '[{"id":1,"firstname":"xx","lastname": "yy"},{"id":2,"firstname": "one","lastname": "two"}]';
ADD_LINK(dt);

console.log(countLinks);
```

Comment: My initial data exists in a vuex store, thus it must come from a getter method.

Comment: @Gandalf yes, of course, this is just for the sake of the demo. Instead of getting the ``users`` from ``data``, you can use a getter

Comment: @Gandalf I updated the answer with another possible solution given your example

Comment: This gives this error when using it on my domain VM3767:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0

Comment: @Gandalf make sure it's a JSON STRING you're parsing

Comment: I should stringfy it?

Comment: If it's a valid JSON you don't have to use ``JSON.parse``. If it's a string as shown in the question, do the above solution

Answer (score 0):

you have to store the data as is, rather than converting into string

```
addLink: function() {
  var dt = [
    {
      "id":1,
      "firstname": "xx",
      "lastname": "yy"
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "firstname": "one",
      "lastname": "two"
    }
  ];

  // remove the single quote from the above array

  this.ADD_LINK(dt)
  this.newLink = '';
},
```

In case you are getting the `var dt` from external source then you should consider converting into valid js json format using this:

```
addLink: function() {
var dt = '[{"id":1,"firstname":"xx","lastname": "yy"},{"id":2,"firstname": "one","lastname": "two"}]';

// parse it to json format
var parsedDt = JSON.parse(dt);

  // add the `parsedDt`
  this.ADD_LINK(parsedDt)
  this.newLink = '';
},
```

Comment: This does not not display any data in `<li v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
    {{ user.firstname }}</li>`

Comment: Try console log the `this.countLinks` inside the `computed` to see what actually the data is.